# Mean of the values that have less than 10 months in stock

Tags: r, data.table

So I have a datatable (dt) with the following elements, an id of an Item ,the date and  stock on that day.

```
ID        date             Stock
193sd      2016-03-23        12
238ds      2016-04-20         1
193sd      2017-09-12         1
...
```

So For example, an ID like **193sd** has different dates

```
ID        date             Stock
193sd    2016-03-23          12
193sd    2017-09-12          1
193sd    2018-09-11          4
193sd    2017-01-12          2
193sd    2016-02-11          1
```

I need to find from the newest date 10 months ago the mean of the stock, manually I know i should do the following operations:

For that ID 193sd

1. SORT the dt$date from newest to oldest
2. get M the number of months between date(i) and date(i+1)

   `dates=c(dateNew, dateOld)
   dates2 <- strptime(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
   dif <- diff(as.numeric(dates2)) # difference in seconds
   months = dif/(60 * 60 * 24 * 30) # months`
3. check if M<=10
4. if true find mean of the stock for those dates for that ID and finish

   The mean is the sum of the values of dt$stock divided to 10
5. if false repeat

As a programmer of other languages and new to R I always think for loops but im sure there is a better cleaner why when working with datatables.

Comment: can u be more specific...u r clubbing more questions in to one question or making different things ?

Comment: The question is so clear Finding the mean of stock 10 months , but I am trying to add as much details and approaches I did

Comment: mean of stock per month or per id basis or with the combination ?

Comment: For each ID obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the packages `data.table` and `lubridate` you could do the followin'

```
library(data.table); library(lubridate);

df <- read.table(text = 
"ID      date                Stock
193sd    2016-03-23          12
193sd    2017-09-12          1
193sd    2018-09-11          4
193sd    2018-01-12          NA
193sd    2017-12-11          1", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

dt <- as.data.table(df) 
dt[, date := as.Date(date)]
result <- dt[, .SD[date >= max(date) %m-% months(10)], by = ID][, .(customMean = sum(Stock, na.rm = T)/10), by = ID] #calculate the mean stock as you described for entries in date that are within 10 months from the last date for each ID
##      ID customMean
##1: 193sd        0.5
```

Comment: This looks good but I get error Error in sum("Stock") : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
I believe because I have NAs

Comment: inn order to get sum excluding NAs you should do `sum(..., na.rm = T)` as you can see now in the edit

Comment: I just checked and `result` for a certian ID given 10 months has 120 records, so doing the mean to those 120 records should be different ??

Comment: can you provide more data? Make dput of first 100 rows of your data and paste it above into an edit

Comment: let's continue on chat

Comment: my data is confidencial but basically i have IDs with more than 100 records so when we filter by less than 10months we keep them because they are recorder in less than 10 months